# how to build yeoman angular-fullstack without minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin, angular-fullstack

I would like to use the build task of the Gruntfile that is part of a yeoman angular-fullstack project. However I would like to have the JS code still readable and also want to avoid asset filenames to be renamed.

so far I changed the Gruntfile in the following:

1. Change default flow behavior in useminPrepare

in gruntfile:

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html'],
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',

    // default flow behavior : https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#flow
    // change the default flow behavior
    flow: {
      steps: {
        js: ['concat'],
        css: ['concat']
      },
      post: {}
    }


  }
}
```

2. Do not execute imagemin or svgmin

in gruntfile:

```
    concurrent: {
      // ...
      dist: [
        'sass',
        // 'imagemin',
        // 'svgmin'
      ]
    },
```

3. Change build task

in gruntfile:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'injector:sass',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'injector',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'autoprefixer',
    'ngtemplates',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    //'cssmin',
    //'uglify',
    // 'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);
```

When I build my project I see

1. js code is now in all in app.js but readable so its fine
2. assets/images is missing
3. html partials are missing. Only the index.html is there

Can anyone help me set up a build process for the dist folder that still has the right file names for images and html and js code still readable ?
The source files can be in one big file but they should still be readable.

Answer (score 1):

Add back the imagemin and svgmin-tasks, they just try to compress the images you use, they won't render your code unreadable.

Comment: Thanks you are right this was not part of my solution. But it doesn't solve the other problems though